# print (encoding/edcoding) French characters works in txt file but incorrect in excel/csv [python]

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, string-decoding

I was given a string with special characters (which should be french characters) and want to make it display correctly in csv/excel:

```
s1 = 'BenoÃ®t'

# take a look at encoding
print(s1.encode(encoding='utf-8'))

# print to txt
with open("firstname.txt", "w") as text_file:
    print(s1, file=text_file)

# print to csv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'FirstName': [s1]})
df.to_csv('firstname.csv', index = False)
```

The results txt file displays the French correctly, but the csv doesn't.

[image]

My question is how to made csv display it correctly? (I can copy the French character from txt to csv, but how to programmatically write the csv and display it correctly?)

---

UPDATE:
thanks to @snakecharmerb and i tried `encoding = 'utf-8-sig'`

```
# try csv with encoding = 'utf-8-sig': doesn't work
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [s1]})
df.to_csv('firstname.csv', index = False, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')



# read from txt file which seems to display correctly
df = pd.read_table("firstname.txt", header = None)
df
#         0
# 0  Benoît

# then write to csv with encoding = 'utf-8-sig' - works
df.to_csv('firstname1.csv', index = False, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel will not necessarily recognise that the file is encoded as UTF-8.  You can specify UTF-8 as the encoding when opening the file in Excel, or you can write the csv file with the 'utf-8-sig' encoding.

'utf-8-sig' is a Windows-specific version of Excel which inserts a a three character "byte order mark" (BOM) and the beginning of the file.  Windows applications trying to guess a file's encoding will read the BOM and decode the file from UTF-8.   The BOM may not be recognised on other platforms, resulting in three unusual characters appearing at the beginning of the file.